# Accessing WiFiPhy from a recevied callback in NS3

Tags: c++, wifi, simulator, ns-3

I want to access the WiFiPhy inside the reception callback of NetDevice with signature.

```
typedef Callback< bool, Ptr<NetDevice>, Ptr<const Packet>, uint16_t, const Address & > ReceiveCallback;
```

Inside the callback, i'm the the casting the NetDevice to WiFiDevice like to WiFiPhy functions.

```
Ptr<WifiNetDevice> wifiNetDevice = DynamicCast<WifiNetDevice>(device);
Ptr<WifiPhy> wifiPhyDev = wifiNetDevice->GetPhy();
```

But I am getting a segmentation fault during the run ? What actually im doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found it..  when you create a *NetDeviceContainer* the object is of type *NetDevice* which does not have any *WifiPhy*. The solution is to DynamicCast it into *WifiNetDevice* and send the frame.

```
Ptr<WifiNetDevice> wifiNetDevice = DynamicCast<WifiNetDevice>(netDevice);
```